# Image URL doesn't retrieve image

Tags: django, image, heroku, django-admin

I load an image to my server side in **django-admin** with `ImageField`.
My server is deployed to **Heroku**.

I browse a .png image and search his path, I received it properly.
After couple of minutes, the server doesn't retrieve the image.

In the server logs, I get status 200 or 301, in both cases I don't get the image.

Anyone have any idea to help me find a way to fix this situation?

**EDIT:**

I find out that it occur because of an `IOError` after reading the image file.
It is happening with two files from a total of three (the third one is .png and is showing properly and his size is a bit smaller) I think it means, it won't always happend and there is no problem with the path because of it.

**EDIT 2:**

The way I thought i solved it, didn't worked.
any other idea?

Comment: There is high chance that there is something wrong with paths. Please add your MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, ImageField code from model and serializer and image-url that is passed by your server to browser.

Comment: Also if you're on Heroku you need to store the image somewhere other than on the filesystem.

Comment: Why shouldn't I do that? Where should I save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fian mentioned in the comments:

> There is high chance that there is something wrong with paths. Please
>   add your MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, ImageField code from model and
>   serializer and image-url that is passed by your server to browser.

What I believe was the problem is, Heroku auto collectstatic to my staticfiles directory.

When I uploaded an image, I had no MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings.
Because of this, every image I uploaded was saved in the BASE_ROOT temporary and I had access to him.

Once in a while Heroku collectstatic my files to my static directory and I lost my connection to those files because of it. I was searching for those files in my BASE_DIR and they have been moved to the staticfiles directory.